# how do i test to see if my program is storing info or writing over it

Tags: c

ok i have incluced my structure as well as my pointer, here is what i am trying to figure out, i need to store up to 5 peoples profiles, but i do not know how to store these in my array while using a pointer
if i don't have the pointer i can do it like this: 
strcpy(user[0].UserName,"whatevername");
strcpy(user[0].UserName,"whateverpwd");

but how do i specify where in the array i want the info while using a point that points to my structure.. i hope this makes sense i don't think i can explain it any better

```
struct profile
{
char First[15];
char Last[15];
char Pwd[10];
char UserName[10];
};

struct profile user[100];
struct profile *puser;
puser=&user[0];



void add_user(struct profile *puser)
{
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
 int quit = 0;
 char fname[30];
 char lname[30];
 char username[30];
 char password[30];

 do
 {
 printf("Enter the first name of the user:\n");
 fgets((puser+i)->First,15, stdin);
 printf("Enter the last name of the user:\n");
 fgets((puser+i)->Last, 15, stdin);
 printf("Enter the username:\n");
 fgets((puser+i)->UserName, 30, stdin);
 printf("Enter the password:\n");
 fgets((puser+i)->Pwd, 30, stdin);


 printf("the first name is: %s\n", (puser+i)->First);
 printf("the last name is: %s\n", (puser+i)->Last);
 printf("the user name is: %s\n", (puser+i)->UserName);
 printf("the password name is: %s\n", (puser+i)->Pwd);
 j++;
 printf("enter 0 to exit 1 to continue:");
 scanf("%d", &quit);
 if(quit == 0)
 printf("goodbye");
 i++;
 getchar();
 }while(quit == 1);
}
```

Comment: would recommend stepping through using a debugger and examining the array values.

Comment: well i tried to repost the code but it will not let me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
char First[15];
char Last[15];
char Pwd[10];
char UserName[10];
}profile;

profile user[100];
profile *puser = user;

void add_user(profile *puser);

void add_user(profile *puser)
{
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
 int quit = 0;
 char fname[30];
 char lname[30];
 char username[30];
 char password[30];

 do
 {

     printf("Enter the first name of the user:\n");
     fgets(puser[i].First,15, stdin);
     printf("Enter the last name of the user:\n");
     fgets(puser[i].Last, 15, stdin);
     printf("Enter the username:\n");
     fgets(puser[i].UserName, 30, stdin);
     printf("Enter the password:\n");
     fgets(puser[i].Pwd, 30, stdin);
     printf("enter 0 to exit 1 to continue:");

     scanf("%d", &quit);
     getchar();
     i++;
 }while(quit == 1);

 for( j = 0; j < i; j++ )
 {

     printf("first name[%d] is: %s\n", j,(puser+j)->First);
     printf("last name[%d] is: %s\n", j,(puser+j)->Last);
     printf("user name[%d] is: %s\n", j,(puser+j)->UserName);
     printf("password[%d] is: %s\n", j,(puser+j)->Pwd);
 }

 printf("Goodbye\n");

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    add_user(puser);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basically without a debugger you just print the array of profiles in a loop after data entry is finished.

Comment: @jimnorton....thank you i like that that way i see where i am at in the array...awesome!